# How to prevent re-render when using react material ui dialogs

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm using modals from the react-material-ui library for a project, and I noticed a side effect when trying to open/close the dialog component. Try this code ([code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/on0y6?file=/src/App.js)):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const timeStamp = moment().format("HH:mm:ss SS");

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Mui Dialog</h1>
      <h2>Rendered on {timeStamp}</h2>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open simple dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open}>
        <DialogTitle>This is a simple dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You'll see that clicking on the button open will cause a re-render and closing the dialog will have the same effect, it's normal because state changed after calling hooks. This is often undesirable, I don't want to re-render the page when opening or after closing.

So I tried to use the following solution, based of refs ([code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-dialog-useref-hook-bwmii?file=/src/App.js)):

```
import { useState, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import "./styles.css";

const SimpleDialog = forwardRef(({ title }, ref) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const innerRef = useRef();

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    openDialog: () => setOpen(true),
    closeDialog: () => setOpen(false)
  }));

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} ref={innerRef}>
      <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Close
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const timeStamp = moment().format("HH:mm:ss SS");

  const dialogRef = useRef();

  const handleOpen = () => {
    dialogRef.current.openDialog();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Mui Dialog</h1>
      <h2>Rendered on {timeStamp}</h2>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open simple dialog
      </Button>
      <SimpleDialog ref={dialogRef} title="This is a simple dialog" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is: is this a correct approach to solve the problem of unwanted re-renders in the case of react-material-ui modals ?

Regards.

Comment: yes that is normal. It is causing a re-render beacuse of the state change.

Comment: Have you tried useEffect with useSate?

Comment: @RichardHpa already mentioned in the question

Comment: @Coder1 I tried the solution using ref, my question is, is there another solution to avoid this type of re-render